Membrane & Top Soil on top of Pea Gravel Land Drain
Dug a trench, put a pea gravel base in, laid a perforated pipe, covered with pea gravel.
I now want to reinstate the grass on these trenches. Can I membrame them first then add top soil and then turf. Will this affect my drainage system?

Yes, you want to use landscape fabric otherwise known as a geotextile.  Either wrap the pipe in it or put a strip on top of the pea gravel in the trench.
This will prevent soil moving downwards due to the action of water and filling the spaces in the pipe and between the pea gravel.
If you have hot summers where grass dries out make sure the top of the pea gravel is at least six inches below the top of the grass.  Otherwise the grass will go brown or not do as well during dry times.
